# Get value from view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have two table User & Article the relationship between tables are

Model:

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

  public static $table = 'article';

  public function User()
    {
    return $this->has_one('user', 'id');
    }
```

and

```
class User extends Eloquent {

  public static $table = 'user';

  public function Article()
    {
       return $this->belongs_to('article', 'id_user');
    }
```

I want to get name value from User directly on Article view but don't works with error
Trying to get property of non-object

My Controller:

```
public function action_index()
    {

    $Article = Article::order_by('id')->paginate(10);

    return View::make('article.index')->with('$articles', $Article);
    }
```

My View:

```
@foreach ($articles->results as $Arti)
      <tr>
       <td>{{$Arti->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$Arti->tag}}</td>
       <td>{{$Arti->user->name }}</td>  <------ ERROR
       <td>{{$Arti->content}}</td>
       <td>{{$Arti->date}}</td>
       <td>
```

Comment: First of all, please explain your relationships: Does `1` user have `n` articles and `1` article belong to `1` user? If that's correct, your relationship declarations do not make sense.

Comment: Article have only 1 USER but i have many Articles...TABLE ARTICLE (id incremental, tag varchar(10), user_id integer, content text, date DATETIMESTAMPS)..Table Articole LINK TO User by user_id

Comment: You should use `belongs_to` on your Article class, and `has_many` on your user User class - an article belongs to a user, and a user has many articles. Right?

Comment: Yes, I corrected but when i call <td>{{$Arti->user->name }}</td> have an error: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the below, a few things are different to yours...

1. Article belongs_to User  (not has_one)
2. User [has_many](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#one-to-many) Article    (not belongs_to)
3. Your relationships should be named in lowercase, plural for has_many (i.e. `articles` or `user`)
4. Your relationship subjects should be class names (i.e. `Article` or `User`)
5. Foreign keys should be name relationship_id, i.e. `user_id`
6. Add `::with()` to your query to [eager load relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#eager)
7. When you [paginate](http://laravel.com/docs/views/pagination#using-the-query-builder) you need to access `->results` in your view

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    // 3: lowercase 'user'
    public function user()
    {
        // 1: Article belongs to User
        // 4: class name 'User'
        // 5: Foreign key on article table is user_id
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }

}

// models/user.php

class User extends Eloquent {

    // 3: lowercase plural 'articles'
    public function articles()
    {
        // 2: User has many Articles
        // 4: class name 'Article'
        return $this->has_many('Article');
    }

}

// controllers/articles.php

class Article_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index()
    {
        // 6: Eager load the user relationship, ::with('user')
        $articles = Article::with('user')->order_by('id')->paginate(10);
        return View::make('articles.index', compact('articles'));
    }

}

// views/articles/index.blade.php
// 7: access $articles->results from the paginator

@foreach ($articles->results as $article)

    <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
    <p>By {{ $article->user->name }}</p>

@endforeach

{{ $articles->links() }}
```